# Unable to update UILabel with JSON data

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to display a UILabel with a string from a REST API using JSON, but have had no luck. I can print the string to the console just fine, but when trying to display this string with a UILabel it appears blank.

This is the test code I am working with :

```
import UIKit

class List {
  var title = String()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let list = List()
    callAPI()
    let width = view.bounds.width
    let height = view.bounds.height
    let label: UILabel = {
      let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: height/2 - 50, width: width, height: 50))
      label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
      label.text = title
     return label
    }()
    view.addSubview(label)
    print("Label Text: \(list.title)")
  }
}

let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/")

func callAPI() {
  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {
    (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
      print(error!)
      return
    }
    do {
      let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray
      let array = json[0] as! [String:Any]
      let title = array["title"] as! String
      print("Title: \(title)")
      let list = List()
      list.title = title
    }
    catch let jsonError {
      print(jsonError)
    }
  }).resume()
}
```

Comment: What is the use of your `List` class and the `list` property?

Comment: the code `label.text = title` runs immediately, before the call to the API begins.  you can expect the title from the JSON only during or after the completion handler has run.  That's why you should take rmaddy advice and update the UI in that handler.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you want to replace these lines:

```
let list = List()
list.title = title
```

with:

```
label.text = title
```

The code you have creates, updates, and discards a `List` instance but makes no attempt to update your actual `UILabel`.

You also need to move the call to `callAPI()` after you create and setup the label.

Comment: which "let list = List()" are you referring to?

Comment: You only have those two lines of code in one place, just after parsing the JSON data.

Comment: ok, but now I get this error... "Use of unresolved identifier "label"

Comment: I just noticed that `callAPI` is not inside your `ViewController` class. Either move `callAPI` inside your `ViewController` class or pass the label as a parameter to the `callAPI` method.

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewController, you've created an instance of `List()`, but `callAPI()` creates its own instance of `List()` and updates that title property instead of the title property of the instance in your ViewController.

You can either remove the `callAPI()` method, put the code directly in your ViewController and update `label.text` directly, you can have `callAPI` accept a parameter of type `UILabel` and update it like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let width = view.bounds.width
        let height = view.bounds.height

        let label: UILabel = {
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: height/2 - 50, width: width, height: 50))
            label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            return label
        }

        callAPI(label)

        view.addSubview(label)
        print("Label Text: \(list.title)")
    }
}

let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/")

func callAPI(_ label: UILabel) {
  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {
    (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
      print(error!)
      return
    }
    do {
      let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray
      let array = json[0] as! [String:Any]
      let title = array["title"] as! String
      print("Title: \(title)")

      label.text = title
    }
    catch let jsonError {
      print(jsonError)
    }
  }).resume()
}
```

, or you can have `callAPI` take an instance of `List()` as a parameter and update the `title` property:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let list = List()
        callAPI(list)

        let width = view.bounds.width
        let height = view.bounds.height

        let label: UILabel = {
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: height/2 - 50, width: width, height: 50))
            label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            label.text = list.title
            return label
        }

        view.addSubview(label)
        print("Label Text: \(list.title)")
    }
}

let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/")

func callAPI(_ list: List) {
  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {
    (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
      print(error!)
      return
    }
    do {
      let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray
      let array = json[0] as! [String:Any]
      let title = array["title"] as! String
      print("Title: \(title)")

      list.title = title
    }
    catch let jsonError {
      print(jsonError)
    }
  }).resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a [closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) in your asynchronous network function?

What's happening with your code is that you dispatch your network call (which takes some significant amount of time). While the network call is being handled, your code continues to execute. Meaning your line `label.text = title` gets called before the network call finishes. At some point, the network call finishes and executes your code to create the list. However, the label text has long (in computer terms) since been set.

Using a closure you can specify that you want the code to run after the JSON has been fetch, serialized, and turned into a `List` object.

The code below adds a closure parameter to your `callAPI` function. Like any other parameter, this parameter has a name, `completion`. After the network call executes, you call this parameter and whatever code is passed in will be executed at that point.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        callAPI { (list) in
            let width = self.view.bounds.width
            let height = self.view.bounds.height
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: height/2 - 50, width: width, height: 50))
            label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            label.text = list.title
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.view.addSubview(label)
            })
            print("Label Text: \(list.title)")
        }
    }

    let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/")

    func callAPI(completion: @escaping (_ list: List) -> Void) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray
                let array = json[0] as! [String:Any]
                let title = array["title"] as! String
                print("Title: \(title)")
                let list = List()
                list.title = title

                completion(list)
            }
            catch let jsonError {
                print(jsonError)
            }
        }).resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one code.

```
import UIKit

class List {
    var title = String()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var list = List()

let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/")
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    callAPI()

}

func setLable() {
    let width = view.bounds.width
    let height = view.bounds.height
    let label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: height/2 - 50, width: width, height: 50))
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        label.text = list.title
        return label
    }()
    self.view.addSubview(label)
    print("Label Text: \(list.title)")
}


func callAPI() {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray
            let array = json[0] as! [String:Any]
            let title = array["title"] as! String
            print("Title: \(title)")
            self.list.title = title
            self.setLable()
        }
        catch let jsonError {
            print(jsonError)
        }
    }).resume()
  }
}
```